# How does Pytorch handles backpropagation in this case?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

```
class ExNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExNet,self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1024,500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500,100)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100,10)


    def forward(self,x,mask1, mask2):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) 
        x = x * mask
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = x * mask2
        x = F.softmax(self.fc3(x),dim=1)
        return x
```

I have some customized masks (depending on the layer) that I would like to apply to my network. According to the code above, does Pytorch consider the masked features during backpropagation? I mean will my gradients during backpropagation be multiplied using these custom masks?

Comment: Yes, as long as the network inputs are torch tensors then autograd will correctly propagate the gradients, taking into account the multiplication by mask.

Comment: Thanks. But should I still specify on my mask tensor: requires_grad= True?

Comment: You don't need to specify requires_grad on any of the inputs unless you for some reason need gradients w.r.t. your inputs